# Why aren't some of my variables showing up in my spring API response?

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring controller that let's me sign in and supposed to return user details(roles, username) in response when entering correct credentials but instead only return the jwt token and username. Here's the api response:

```
{

"username": "adam",

"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZGFtIiwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiJdLCJpYXQiOjE1NTcyMzUxMTMsImV4cCI6MTU1NzIzODcxM30.PksRTzgYu6r79KNmc4YDNXGqO1Ke63oOzzoPjURUY9k"

}
```

**My controller:**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.domain.User;
import com.example.demo.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.demo.security.jwt.JwtTokenProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.ok;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

@Autowired
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

@Autowired
UserRepository users;

@PostMapping("/signin")
public ResponseEntity signin(@RequestBody User user) {

    try {
        String username = user.getUsername();
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, user.getPassword()));
        String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(username, this.users.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username " + username + "not found")).getRoles());

        Map<Object, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("username", username);
        model.put("token", token);
        model.put("roles", user.getRoles());
        return ok(model);
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username/password supplied");
    }
}
}
```

**My entity:**

```
package com.example.demo.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 357523406648925755L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="username")
private String username;

@Column(name="firstname")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="lastname")
private String lastName;


@NotEmpty
@Column(name="password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "email")
@NotEmpty()
private String email;

@Column(name = "enabled")
private boolean enabled;


@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Builder.Default
private List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return this.roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(toList());
}
@JsonIgnore
@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}
@JsonSetter
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}
@JsonIgnore
@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}
@JsonIgnore
@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}
@JsonIgnore
@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: What is user.getRoles() get returning? Is it returning null?

Comment: It's supposed to return a list containing the roles instead it doesn't return anything in the API response

Comment: And in this specific case, for user "adam", is it returning null? Are you getting any errors? You cannot always add a null value to a Map, so it would not be added in this case: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-

Comment: Actually I just tried System.out.print(user.getRoles()) it returned an empty list for some reason even though the 'adam' user has 'ROLE_ADMIN'  in it's role property.

Comment: Ok, well if I were you I would hard code something instead of user.getRoles() just to test and see if it is added. If it is added, then you know the problem lies in returning an empty list and you will need to handle that case. Then I would tackle the issue of trying to figure out why user.getRoles() is empty instead of showing ROLE_ADMIN. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry but how can i hard code it?

Comment: You can switch model.put("roles", user.getRoles()) to something like model.put("roles", "HARDCODED_TEST_STRING") and/or try sending a List<string> that has at least one string in it. This is only for testing/debugging, so you would change your code back after.